# REST GET ResourceResponse returns encoded json

Tags: 8

I have a decoupled drupal project with an angular 5 front end that is utilizing a restful api to store data.  Because this API needed a key that we didn't want to expose we have created a restful endpoint in the Drupal code that acts as a sort of proxy.  The front end hits Drupal, Drupal adds the key, hits the api, and then Drupal returns the api's response to the front end.

When I hit the API directly, I get clean JSON:

```
{"total":610,"results": .....
```

But when I use the proxy, I get encoded json:

```
"{\u0022total\u0022:610,\u0022results\u0022:[{\u0022_id\u0022:\u .....
```

My Angular request:

```
get(): Observable<RecipePreview[]> {
    let encryptedAuthorizationString = 'BLAHBLAHBLAH';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .set("X-CSRF-Token", this._HttpServiceService.csrfToken)
        .set("Authorization", "basic " + encryptedAuthorizationString)
    ;

    let u = this.filter.url();

    return this._http.get(u,{headers})
        .map(res => {
                return res;
            }
        )
    ;
}
```

The Drupal RESTful endpoint code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Responds to entity GET requests.
 * @param $data
 * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
 * @throws \GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException
 */
public function get() {
    $url="BLAHBLAHBLAH";

    $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
    try {
        $request = $client->request('GET', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'apikey' => "BLAH-BLAH-BLAH"
            ],
        ]);

        $file_contents = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    }
    catch (RequestException $e) {
        //An error happened.
        $file_contents = "There was an error.";
    }

    \Drupal::logger('Proxy API')->debug($file_contents);

    return new ResourceResponse($file_contents);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that ResourceResponse is doing something to the json, and there has got to be a way to tell it to not do it anymore?  But how?  Thoughts?

I'm also using the same final end point in a drupal content migration from source and I believe this formatting is causing issues with that as well.

Thanks so much for helping me out with this!

Comment: Is it double encoded?

Comment: You could simply return a Symfony JsonResponse, I think there is no code in Drupal interfering with this response.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin was on to it.  It was being double encoded.  I have to return a response, so I decode the results from the first api, then return it as a json response:

```
return new JsonResponse( json_decode($file_contents) );
```